# how to set distance between cells in grid in cytoscape js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

I made a graph in cytoscape js using a grid layout and I specified the row and col for each node.

However the graph being rendered is very zoomed out and the spacing between the nodes is very large. I fixed this problem partially by specifying the number of rows and columns for the grid layout (see [picture](http://karasu.byethost5.com/graph1.png). Although specifying the number of rows and columns is not desired as the size of the graph can change.

The resulting graph (when specifying the rows and columns) is still not optimum, the nodes are still rendered too small and the distance between them horizontally is still quite large.

Is there anyway to specify the distance between the grid cells?

My current code for the grid layout looks as follows:

```
layout: {
    name: 'grid',
    padding: 30,
    rows: 20,
    columns: 10,
    fit: true,
    position: function( node ){ return {row:node.data('row'), col:node.data('col')}; } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `grid` layout automatically uses the dimensions of your nodes and the available space to position the nodes in the graph.  If you're looking for new functionality, please [file an issue](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/new) describing the feature you would like.

Thanks for using Cytoscape.js.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe filthy hack, but it works for me.
Just find function in cytoscape code for grid layout:

```
GridLayout.prototype.run
```

In this function find lines like:

```
var cellWidth = bb.w / cols;
var cellHeight = bb.h / rows;
```

Just add some multipliers to `cellWidth` and `cellHeight`, like below:

```
var cellWidth = bb.w / cols * 2.5;
var cellHeight = bb.h / rows / 4;
```

Also you can extract  multipliers like layout params.